# Alphabetical serial Number in Gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

In my ASPX+VB web, I have some Gridview to display data. Earlier I used Numerical serial numbers like 1,2 3. The code is appended below.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Ser">
   <ItemTemplate><%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %></ItemTemplate>
   <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" /> 
   <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="35px"/>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

But on another page I want `N=Alphabetical serial number` like `(a)  (b) (c)`

Comment: In another page I want Alphabetical serial number like (a) (b) (c)

Comment: `((Char)(65 + Container.DataItemIndex)).ToString()`